# Convert VARCHAR to DATE in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to convert my varchar to date.

My varchar looks like this:

| event_date |
| --- |
| 2020-09-20 |
| 2021-07-21 |
| 2021-01-20 |
| 2020-10-08 |

Here is my attempted solution:

```
SELECT
  TO_DATE(event_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM
  database.schema.table
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Can't parse ' ' as date with format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Can anybody help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Exception says it is empty string or space: Can't parse ' ' as date

Comment: Still get all nulls when I try this:

SELECT
  event_date,
  try_to_date(trim(event_date),'yyyy-mm-dd ')  as parsed_date1,
  try_to_date(event_date,'yyyy-mm-dd ')  as parsed_date2

Comment: And what is original date (varchar) which can not be parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use try_to_date(event_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'), it will return NULL (will not fail) if event_date can not be parsed, you can filter and check what exactly it contains:

```
SELECT
  event_date                           as varchar_date,
  TRY_TO_DATE(event_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') as parsed_date
FROM
  database.schema.table
WHERE TRY_TO_DATE(event_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') IS NULL --filter and check
```

After checking which formats do you have, you can parse different formats using coalesce:

```
coalesce(TRY_TO_DATE(event_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),
         TRY_TO_DATE(event_date,'YYYYMMDD')
         )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried and they all came back as null :(

Comment: @cyahahn Even with dates like in your example 2020-09-20 ?

Comment: Yup unfortunately all came back null

Comment: @cyahahn can it be something else, not normal dash '-' ? Then you can try to copy it from your string

Comment: Actually I figured out I had an extra space in my code 'yyyy-mm-dd '

Comment: @cyahahn Great!

Answer (score 1):

Answer was the trim() function for the extra spaces around my varchar. Thanks everyone!